# How do I add an entryUUID field to the FreeIPA compat schema?

Tags: ldap, freeipa, ldif

I am trying to add an `entryUUID` field to groups in the FreeIPA compat schema, but I am struggling to create the required `attributeType`. My LDIF for creating it is:

```
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: attributeTypes
attributeTypes: ( entryUUID-oid
    NAME 'entryUUID'
    DESC 'UUID of the entry'
    EQUALITY uuidMatch
    ORDERING uuidOrderingMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.1.16.1
    SINGLE-VALUE )
```

This is based on the specification from [RFC4530](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4530#section-2.4), except with the `USAGE directoryOperation` and `NO-USER-MODIFICATION` lines removed. These need to be removed because the `compat` schema doesn't support operational attributes (I think). The error I get is as follows:

```
modifying entry "cn=schema"
ldap_modify: Invalid syntax (21)
        additional info: attribute type entryUUID: Unknown attribute syntax OID "1.3.6.1.1.16.1"
```

I don't think this makes much sense at all, since OID 1.3.6.1.1.16.1 should be built in, right? Obviously my next course of action was to try and redefine the syntax with a different OID, but there is no documentation of how to do that anywhere, so I suspect it's not possible. I then tried removing the `SYNTAX` line (not allowed), and setting the syntax to "domain string" (can't use the `uuidMatch` equality).

In case this is an XY problem, I'm doing this in order to get vSphere to link up with FreeIPA, since vSphere requires a `entryUUID` field.

To summarise:

- How do I correctly add a custom UUID attribute to the `compat` schema?
- Do I even need to?

Comment: have you looked over this post - https://www.freeipa.org/page/HowTo/vsphere5_integration

Comment: @JacobEvans Yes, I have. I am using vSphere 7, not 5 though. I have used a lot of information from that article to get the other schema details that vSphere requires, but `entryUUID` is the only thing remaining.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I need to get `entryuuid`s added to the groups on my FreeIPA and it's proving tremendously difficult to find good information on this topic.

Comment: @AndrewBobulsky Sadly, I never figured it out. We moved our infrastructure to Proxmox last year, so I don't expect I'll work it out any time soon either.